# Android: Not able to read /storage/emulated folder

Tags: android

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulator");
File[] list = file.listFiles();
```

list is returning `null`. I've already taken READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. There is a path like this in that folder `"/storage/emulator/0"`. I'm trying to read that `/0/` folder. I'm able to access `/storage/emulator/0` using `Environment.getExternalDirectory()` but I'm parsing every file in android storage. I'm doing it like this

```
String root_sd = System.getenv("ANDROID_STORAGE");      //root_sd = "/storage"
file = new File(root_sd);
list = file.listFiles();
```

then for every file in list array I do the same thing.

But for some reason it is not able to read directory of `/storage/emulated/`. How do I read this storage?

Comment: What is the reason you are not using `Environment.getExternalDirectory()` as a file path? Since this gives you access to folder `/0/` - then pass this path to the `new File(path)`.

Comment: "I'm parsing every file in android storage" -- you do not have access to arbitrary locations.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla sd-card is accessible from /storage/sd-card. That's why I need to parse everything in /storage

Comment: @CommonsWare but I think I've access to /storage

Comment: "but I think I've access to /storage" -- no, you do not. "sd-card is accessible from /storage/sd-card" -- not on Android 4.4+.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have android 6.0 and my sd card is at "/storage/9058-abc/", (9058-abc.... it's actually some other id but you got the gist)

Comment: No, my point is that you have no arbitrary access to removable storage on Android 4.4+.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the 0 folder that is the reason why it is not accessible.
So, to open the internal sd card you have to use getexternalstoragedirectory() for devices starting from api 23.

For android version below M you are able to access the 0 folder.

For my powerful music player application in android I have hard coded for android versions M and above to jump to getexternalstoragedirectory() directory when emulated is clicked.
To see how it works
Check the app link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ac.themusicplayer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, consider including that link above ONLY as reference or tutorial without describing its connection to you, your company, or anything as it might be considered as advertisement.